# Bitting of nails during fast

Tags: practical-islam, sawm, ramadan

I have a habit of bitting nails.I listen that during fasting is a person bite nail, the fast breaks. is it correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Biting the nails itself does not break the fast, however swallowing them would break the fast.

Notwithstanding, biting the nails is a vile, reprehensible act especially as there can be filth under the nails. One should endeavour to break this habit. Speak to your Local GP, who can advise accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Biting the nails itself does not break the fast, however swallowing them would break the fast.